# Best way to edit and reorder all elements in a PriorityBlockingQueue?

Tags: java, priority-queue

i have a priority queue and i periodically need to edit all the elements in it and then reorder the whole queue. Here is a simple code to illustrate one possible solution.

```
package com.raby.shonguiz.zebi.test.collection;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue;

import com.raby.shonguiz.zebi.test.CustomObject;

public class PriorityBlockingQueueTest {

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException {
        reorderQueue();
    }

    private static void reorderQueue() {
        int nbElements = 10;
        BlockingQueue<CustomObject> priorityBlockingQueue = createQueue( nbElements );
        Collection<CustomObject> col = new ArrayList<CustomObject>( priorityBlockingQueue.size() );
        priorityBlockingQueue.drainTo( col );
        for ( CustomObject cO : col ) {
            editElement( cO, nbElements );
            priorityBlockingQueue.add( cO );
        }
        pollQueue( priorityBlockingQueue );
    }

    private static void editElement( CustomObject cO, int nbElements ) {
        cO.setId( new Random().nextInt( nbElements ) );
    }



    public static BlockingQueue<CustomObject> createQueue( int nbItems ) {
        BlockingQueue<CustomObject> priorityBlockingQueue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<CustomObject>();
        for ( int i = 0; i < nbItems; i++ ) {
            Random rd = new Random();
            priorityBlockingQueue.add( new CustomObject( rd.nextInt( nbItems ) ) );
        }
        return priorityBlockingQueue;
    }

    public static void pollQueue( BlockingQueue<CustomObject> priorityBlockingQueue ) {
        while ( !priorityBlockingQueue.isEmpty() ) {
            System.out.println( priorityBlockingQueue.poll() );
        }
    }

}
```

And this is the CustomObject Class

```
package com.raby.shonguiz.zebi.test;

public class CustomObject implements Comparable<CustomObject> {

    long id;

    public CustomObject() {

    }

    public CustomObject( long id ) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId( long id ) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals( Object obj ) {
        if ( this == obj )
            return true;
        if ( obj == null )
            return false;
        if ( getClass() != obj.getClass() )
            return false;
        CustomObject other = (CustomObject) obj;
        if ( id != other.id )
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append( "CustomObject [id=" );
        builder.append( id );
        builder.append( "]" );
        return builder.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo( CustomObject o ) {
        return Long.compare( id, o.getId() );
    }
}
```

So what i am doing is that i am draining the Queue to a collection, then edit all the elements from the collection and reinsert them, is there any better way (less performance costly) to periodically edit and reorder all the elements of a PriorityQueue ?

Comment: 1) How many threads are doing that? (1/many) 2) Do you reorder all elements / just 1 / some percentage? 3) What's your queue length on average?

Comment: 1/Only one thread is doing the reordering but other threads are writing on the queue as well (add() and poll())
2/All the elements have to be edited and thus reordered as the title suggest
3/ up to 10000 entries maybe

Comment: Building a new one is the only way, but the best way to do anything is not to do it. What brought about this requirement?

Comment: What do you mean building a new one is the only way ? And i need it because i need a data structure that sorts items according to a certain priority, the queue is doing it at removal and elements insertion but not on elements editing which is why i need to refresh it periodically.

Comment: What part of 'building a new one is the only way' don't you understand? Especially as that's exactly what you're doing? And why do you need to edit anything? If you don't allow editing of the priority field, you don't need to rebuild anything of course.